# Setting states of array element in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have this simple form and I am having a hard time in changing and getting the state of this one array.

The state is set

```
this.state = {
            .....
        treatment:              [],
         .....
    }
```

On change

```
onChange= (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        error: ''
    })
}
```

The array element is called on click in form with one array element in it
    
      
        Click Here to add Treatment

On clicking the button the JS kicks in

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#addHidden').click(function(){
    var addtext = $('.hidden_box').html();
        $('#addHiddenBox').append(addtext);
});

$("#addHiddenBox").on("click", ".removeText", function () {
    $(this).closest(".boxAdded").remove();
});

});
```

and brings in this hidden element

```
 <div className="hide hidden_box">           
      <div className="treatments col-sm-6 boxAdded">             
           <div className="form-group">
             <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Treatment" name="treatment[]" value={this.state.treatment} onChange={this.onChange}/>
             <button className="btn btn-danger removeText" type="button"><i className="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
           </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Iam not able to set the state of treatment[] here. The states are coming blank.

Comment: can you check once what the value of `e.target.name` and `e.target.value` is when `onChange` is triggered. Maybe use console.log debugging

Comment: Iam getting this on form submit

{name: "Amit Khare", title: "BEST TREKKING PLACES IN INDIA", short_summary: "aaaaaa", about_you: "bbbbbbb", specialisation: "ccccc", …}
about_you: "bbbbbbb"
city: "Gurgaon"
country: "India"
education: "ffffffff"
error: ""
name: "Amit Khare"
profile_pic: "C:\fakepath\blog-1.jpg"
short_summary: "aaaaaa"
specialisation: "ccccc"
state: "Haryana"
street: "1760, Gurgaon"
title: "BEST TREKKING PLACES IN INDIA"
treatment: []
}

Comment: can you try below code.The console log should tell you what is being set in the state and then you can proceed accordingly. Also, first change the name of the input element to `treatment` and not `treatment[]`, and then try below debugging.
```
onChange= (e) => {
console.log('name', e.target.name);
console.log('value', e.target.value);
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        error: ''
    })
}
```

Comment: Same result.. blank array..
setState is not working here i think....
I changed the initial value to ['a', 'b'] and it returns <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Treatment" name="treatment" value="a,b"> in html

Answer (score 1):

`e.target.name` in your case will return "`treatment[]`". Notice the square brackets.

Change it to this:

```
<input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Treatment" name="treatment" value={this.state.treatment} onChange={this.onChange}/>
```

Comment: Still the state coming blank

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved this

the JSX looks like

```
<div className="form-group">
    <button className="btn btn-success" id="addHidden" type="button" onClick={(e)=>this.addTreatment(e)}><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Click Here to add Treatment</button>
      <div id="addHiddenBox" className="row">
{
    this.state.treatment.map((treatment, index) =>{
       return(        
         <div className="treatments col-sm-6 boxAdded" key={index}>             
          <div className="form-group">
           <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Treatment" name="treatment" value={treatment} onChange={(e)=>this.arrayChange(e, index)}  />
           <button className="btn btn-danger removeText" type="button" onClick={()=>this.arrayRemove(index)}><i className="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
          </div>
         </div>
      )
   })
}
 </div>
</div>
```

The functions are:

```
this.state = {
        ...........
        treatment:              [],
        ..........
    }

addTreatment(){
    this.setState({treatment: [...this.state.treatment, ""]})
}

arrayChange(e, index){
    this.state.treatment[index] = e.target.value
    this.setState({treatment: this.state.treatment})
}

arrayRemove(index){
    this.state.treatment.splice(index, 1)
    this.setState({treatment: this.state.treatment})
}
```